# Mongoose - Remove an object from array of messages

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, chat

I need to remove a message from array of messages in mongoose..How can I do this?
My Schema :

```
const ChatMessages = new Schema({
    room: {
        type: Schema.Types.Mixed,
        required: true
    },
    messages: [{
        sender: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        text: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        display: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        date: {
            type: Date,
            default: Date.now,
        }

    }]
})
```

My code is :

```
await ChatMessages.updateOne({ room },{ $pull: { messages: { _id: new ObjectId(_id) } }}, { multi: true})
```

Document Example

```
id: ObjetId(6051f0bbe23bf3129b8f8eb6)
room:"111"
__v:0
messages: Array
```

Comment: What's the error you are getting here? It seems ok.

Comment: It simply doesn't remove the item :/

Comment: Hmm, maybe there is an issue with "new ObjectId(_id)". Can you try it with { $pull: { messages: { _id } }}. Converting a String to ObjectId may cause such issues.

Comment: I tried it before, but it wasn't working too :/

Comment: Can you add some example document to your question? Maybe I can reproduce it?

Comment: And here it recommends using update instead updateOne: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/#remove-items-from-an-array-of-documents
Have you tried this?

Comment: I add example in my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reproduced the issue with my example document here:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("604bacf4dfe5ed598c350737")
    "array": [
        {
            "_id": ObjectId("60474814a380df6aade743cd"),
            "value": NumberInt(785)
        }
    ]
}
```

If I go with `updateOne()` and `multi` options, it throws an error.
So I executed it with `update()` and `multi`:

```
db.documents.update({ _id: ObjectId("604bacf4dfe5ed598c350737") }, {
    $pull: {
        array: {
            _id: ObjectId("60474814a380df6aade743cd")
        }
    }
}, { multi: true })
```

This is the result document:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("604bacf4dfe5ed598c350737")
    "array": []
}
```

So in your case, keeping the `new ObjectId(_id)` and using `update()` should solve the problem. If there is still a problem with the `$pull`, it means there is an issue with the find query: `{ room }`.

For more info: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/#remove-items-from-an-array-of-documents